# Error with mime-db\db.json when building with webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webpack, mime

I am using webpack and Visual Studio Code to build an Angular 2/nodejs application.

I am having trouble creating my bundle because webpack complains:

```
ERROR in ./~/mime-db/db.json
Module parse failed: c:\ftct\node_modules\mime-db\db.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "application/1d-interleaved-parityfec": {
|     "source": "iana"
|   },
 @ ./~/mime-db/index.js 11:17-37
```

I have tried clearing the npm cache, deleting and reinstalling to no avail. Anyone know what might be causing this issue? I have looked at the mime-db GitHub page but it doesn't have any info on this.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by installing webpack json-loader. (`npm install --save json-loader`)
And then registered it in my webpack config.

```
config = {
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            loader: 'json-loader',
            test: /\.json$/
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: The Following Is For The Most Current Webpack/Babel Config**

I already had json-loader installed in my **Webpack 4/Babel 7/React 16.8.6/Node 11** app but I was still getting this error.  What took care of it for me was adding an '**exclude: /node_modules/**' property to the 
'**test: /.json$/**'.

Like the following snippet:

> webpack.config.js

```
// 'rules: []' is Webpack 4 syntax to replace 'loaders: []'
rules: [  
    { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
    // ... Rules for other loaders ... //
]
```